# I have watched addresses in my wallet..how do i use them?

Tags: private-key, watch-only

How do I use the watch only addresses that are in my wallet? I can't find the private keys. Is their any way to use them or should I just delete the wallet with the watch addresses in them?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have the private keys for those addresses, then they are not yours and you cannot do anything with them. Those addresses and their associated Bitcoin do not belong to you, so you cannot use them.

You can delete the watch only addresses if possible; you will not lose any money if you delete just those addresses because there is no money that belongs to you in the first place with those addresses. However be careful of deleting the wallet entirely, it could have addresses and private keys which do belong to you and those you do not want to delete.